# PHP Cookie works on one page but not another. Debugging reveals that the cookie isn't set

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working on a fairly basic project that, within the scope of the question, contains a few PHP files.

> session.php::session->checkSession()

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["session"])) {
    $this->redirect("login/?h=t"); //Redirect to login page
}
```

The `checkSession` function is called on every page load within the web app.

On every page everything works fine, however, on one page, the user is redirected to */login/?h=t* (I added the 'h=t' bit for the sole reason of differentiating between other places where the user is redirected to the login page. When I create a debug script that just does `var_dump($_COOKIE);`, I get the cookie array which **does** contain the session cookie.

I have run out of things to test since the code says that the cookie does not exist, yet the same code says it does exist.

UPDATE: Clearing cookies in the browser fixes the issues temporarily.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the cookie?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is not the same as `$_COOKIES`. Also, you must run `session_start()` on every page, before any output of any kind. You need to confirm that that is happening in `checkSession()`.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks, sorry, that was a typo. They are both `$_COOKIE`. Could you explain what you mean by running session_start()? I'm not using the in-built session handling?

Comment: @GentlemanMax Here it is: `private function setCookie($sessionId, $expiry) { setcookie("session", $sessionId, $expiry, "/"); }`

Comment: Could you check the cookie parameter "secure", maybe you use https on all pages except that one.

Comment: **Why** aren't you using the built-in session handling? Don't add information in comments, edit your question.

Comment: @miken32 I've updated the question with a bit more debugging information. I'm not using the built-in session handling because a) I'm not familiar with it, and b) the session cookie may, in the event of an API request, be an API token rather a session identifier.